# can host application and website on same port with same ip address in iis?

Tags: iis-8

I have deployed an website in IIS using my public domain name on the same domain some applications already deployed in IIS.The issue is that when we deployed website then the application which is already deployed stop working.I used same port and public domain name for both website as well as application i.e while deploying website our hostname is public domain name to access website from outside.

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you host multiple applications under the same IP, domain and port the other one will stop working. so make them unique by changing one of the IP, port or domain.

or if you want to use the same binding for all site you can host as an application under that site.

for more detail you could refer this link:

[Understanding IIS Bindings, Websites, Virtual Directories, and lastly Application Pools](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrad/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools/)

Answer (score 1):

The port must be distinct for every running service.

Comment: Is it possible to host multiple website on single public domain/Ip address?

Comment: yes you can like this..

<Domain_name>/<website_name>